# R Error: Shadow graphics device error

Tags: r, graph

yes I know there are many threads to this above mentioned error, but (at least I) wasn't able to find a solution.
So RStudio gives me the following error while trying to plot something:

> ```
>     Error in RStudioGD() : 
>     Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
> ```

It seems to be a problem with R supporting jpeg and png.
Running in R environment

```
    >capabilities()
    jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
    FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
    http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
    TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE 
    NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
    TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

shows exactly that. cairo and pango are installed. And I have no idea what else to do.
[Here](https://github.com/clauswilke/dataviz/blob/master/visualizing_uncertainty.Rmd) you can find the code I'm trying to run. I installed the packages magrittr, ggplot2, dplyr, cowplot and patchwork.
  Furthermore I'm running the latest RStudio version on linux. R itself is also updated.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**:
*For anyone stumbling over the same problem: A complete re-installation of R, RStudio and most depencies solved the problem somehow.*

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but today I had the same problem. I restarted my session with Ctrl + Shift + F10 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using R version 3.6.3 (built from source) and RStudio 1.2.5033, on Amazon Linux 4.14.154-99.181.amzn1.x86_64. I first did:

```
sudo yum -y install libX11-devel
```

I then re-installed R from source using the following options

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/R/$3.6.3 --enable-memory-profiling --enable-R-shlib --with-blas --with-lapack --with-x=yes --with-readline=no
```

The key here is --with-x=yes. Finally I did:

```
sudo make

sudo make install
```

After that I was able to generate plots within RStudio. For reference, my capabilities are now:

```
> capabilities()
   jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo 
  FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
 cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
  FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```