# Why does ggplot2 work in R version 3.6.1 but not in R version 3.6.3 on the server?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, r-server

Currently I am working on the R Studio Pro server from my university.
I am trying to plot the following using the library ggplot2:

```
 starttijdstipvanladenvergelijken %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=StartConnectionHour, y = perc)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_point()
```

But unfortunately, I get this error:

**Error in RStudioGD() :
Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
In addition: Warning message:
In grDevices:::png("/tmp/Rtmpn4W7ks/5fd6f31151e54efab921f12ea1e3591b.png",  :
unable to open connection to X11 display ''**

PS: When I switch from R version 3.6.3 to 3.6.1, I don't get an error, only when I am trying to plot the graph in R version 3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

This message indicates you do not have *write* access to folder */tmp/Rtmpn4W7ks/*

Possibly because the folder does not exist (can you create this folder?)

or because you are not the owner, or another file system permissions issue.

See further discussion in thread https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2214

Comment: I created the folder that's 'missing' but it still doesn't work and I still get the same error ..

Comment: Per this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50995461/10276092 - What is the output of this command in both R versions -- `capabilities()`

Comment: In version 3.6.3: 

       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets 
      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE 
     libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE 
long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE

Comment: In version 3.6.1:        jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE 
     libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE 
long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE

Comment: In the capabilities() you posted for version 3.6.3, both "png"  and "cairo" are false. Searching on the "Shadow graphics device error: r error 4" error message you posted, I see many threads about system level libraries needing to be installed, I think you should escalate this issue to the system administrators or helpdesk.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I escalated this issue to my system administrator. Waiting for a reply now ..

Comment: This might happen if they compiled R from source and the compiler didn't see certain libraries (x, png, cairo/pango) or certain `./configure` flags (--with-x, --with-cairo, --with-libpng). I had trouble compiling R and cairo not working - what helped after the fact was the run time option `options(bitmapType='cairo')`

Comment: Give the command in this thread a try too https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31301/367012  `Sys.setenv("DISPLAY"=":0.0")`